# lxml find all elements between two tags

Tags: python, lxml

extracted a word document and search in this all bookmarks. But the bookmark tag have no end tag, so lxml find only the bookmarkStart but not the elements between bookmarkStart and bookmarkEnd. How can i get all Elements within bookmarkStart and bookmarkEnd? Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:oel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2019/extlst" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml/cex" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml" xmlns:w16sdtdh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2020/wordml/sdtdatahash" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se w16cid w16 w16cex w16sdtdh wp14">
    <w:body>
        <w:p w14:paraId="2DDA6990" w14:textId="44789F6F" w:rsidR="0067078D" w:rsidRDefault="003F5B0A">
            <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="testmark"/>
            <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>sometext</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
            <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="0067078D">
            <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
            <w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1417" w:bottom="1134" w:left="1417" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
            <w:cols w:space="708"/>
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

```
from lxml import etree as ET

ns = {'w': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'}
ns2 = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'

with open('document.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as xml_file:
    tree_word = ET.parse(xml_file)

findall_param = 'w:bookmarkStart'
find_param = 'w:t'

root_word = tree_word.getroot()
field_content = tree_word.findall('.//'+findall_param, ns)

for bookmark in field_content:
    textmarker = bookmark.attrib[f"{ns2}name"]
    print(ET.tostring(bookmark))
    t = bookmark.find('.//w:t', ns)
```

Comment: The xml in your question doesn't seem to be a representative sample of the actual xml - for example, namespace declarations are missing. Please edit your question and post a short, well formed, representative xml snippet.

Comment: I updated the question with the xml from word.

Comment: Much better! So given new sample xml - what **exactly** is your expected output? " all Elements within bookmarkStart and bookmarkEnd" isn't clear enough.

Comment: So that i have for each bookmark i have the inner elements. I wanna for example replace the w:t text. <w:t>sometext</w:t> to <w:t>some_new_text</w:t>. When the xml have a end tag, like <bookmark>this and that</bookmark> the findall finds all between, but the word xml doesnt have this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, and based on the sample xml in the question, the following should get you at least close to what you are trying to do:

```
word = """[your sample xml]"""
doc = etree.XML(word.encode())
ns = {'w': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'}
start_param = 'w:bookmarkStart'
t_param = 'w:t'
end_param = "bookmarkEnd"

doc.xpath(f'/{start_param}',namespaces=ns)
for el in doc.xpath(f'//w:p[.//{book_param}]//{book_param}/following-sibling::*',namespaces=ns): 
    if etree.QName(el).localname==f"{end_param}":
        break
    else:
        if len(el.xpath(f'.//{t_param}',namespaces=ns) )>0:
           el.xpath(f'.//{t_param}',namespaces=ns)[0].text="some new text"
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Try it on your actual document and see if it works.